# Sonarqube missing API after upgrade from 5.2 to 5.4

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.4

After upgrading from 5.2 to 5.4 it seems the 'addContainerExtension(..) method has been completely dropped since 5.3.

We relied on this method for injecting our own custom rules. The method does not seem to have been marked deprecated - its purely missing from the API

Our usage of this method is

```
for (ProjectDefinition pd : context.projectReactor().getProjects()) {
            pd.addContainerExtension(ruleSet);
            pd.addContainerExtension(testExecutionService);
            pd.addContainerExtension(resultProvider);
}
```

Any suggestions / help appreicated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API was used to inject some components from the scanner to each module pico container (mainly MavenProject). We have dropped this dangerous feature.

But you don't need to use this to contribute your own rules. Simply pass your extensions in the getExtensions() method of your Plugin class.